# Using struct.unpack() without knowing anything about the string

Tags: python, endianness

I need to parse a big-endian binary file and convert it to little-endian. However, the people who have handed the file over to me seem unable to tell me anything about what data types it contains, or how it is organized — the only thing they know for certain is that it is a big-endian binary file with *some* old data. The function struct.unpack(), however, requires a format character as its first argument.

This is the first line of the binary file:

```
import binascii
path = "BC2003_lr_m32_chab_Im.ised"            
with open(path, 'rb') as fd:
    line = fd.readline()
    print binascii.hexlify(line)
```

> a0040000dd0000000000000080e2f54780f1094840c61a4800a92d48c0d9424840a05a48404d7548e09d8948a0689a48e03fad48a063c248c01bda48c0b8f448804a0949100b1a49e0d62c49e0ed41499097594900247449a0a57f4900d98549b0278c49a0c2924990ad9949a0eba049e080a8490072b049c0c2b849d077c1493096ca494022d449a021de49a099e849e08ff349500a

Is it possible to change the endianness of a file without knowing anything about it?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Here's a tip. Simply grab every 4 bytes from that file, flip them around, and write the result out to a new file. Ship that file off to the people that need it. When they complain that the file does not meet their format standards, ask them to provide you with the verification specification/tool.

Comment: Just to make my point clear. If the **only thing** they know is that it is a file with **some old data**, why do you or they care about what you can or cannot do to/with the file. Delete it, it sounds unimportant.

Comment: Well, they know for sure what data there is in it: not worth going into details, but they are raw values needed to perform scientific computations — they just don't know how the file is structured. Your point still stands, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this without knowing the datatypes. There is little point in attempting to do so otherwise.

Even if it was a homogeneous sequence of one datatype, you'd *still* need to know what you are dealing with; flipping the byte order in `double` values is very different from `short` integers.

Take a look at the [formatting characters table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters); anything with a different byte size in it will result in a different set of bytes being swapped; for `double` values, you need to reverse the order of every 8 bytes, for example.

If you know what data *should* be in the file, then at least you have a starting point; you'd have to puzzle out how those values fit into the bytes given. It'll be a puzzle, but with a target set of values you can build a map of the datatypes contained, *then* write a byte-order adjustment script. If you don't even have that, best not to start as the task is impossible to achieve.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing... :( Mine got downvoted as well pretty much instantly without comment...

Comment: It's probably the usual, where the only good answer is the one that tells the OP how to do what he asked for. When it can't be done, those answers usually attract downvotes.

Comment: Correct, but that doesn't stop people from downvoting I'm afraid. I've seen the same myself when I answer "Sorry, can't be done" + the technical information, gets downvoted, because "that's not what was asked for".

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer is that there is no answer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: exactly. I'll soldier on regardless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your answer is clearly more detailed than mine :) You win this round! :P